# FATAL ERROR: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, xampp

Após a atualização do sistema (para Windows 10 1709) começou a dar o seguinte erro na execução do PHP:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'D:\...\index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

Isso acontece tanto se usar o Built-In do php (`php -S 0.0.0.0:80`) como se usar o serviço do apache do XAMPP.

Porém, se executar o mesmo projeto do drive C: (drive onde está instalado o XMPP) o erro não ocorre.

Alguém sabe explicar o porquê desse comportamento?

**Obs:** Note que o erro é no arquivo **Unknown** na linha **0**... ou seja, ele se perde completamente. Note também que o erro não ocorria antes da Windows atualizar. O erro persistiu mesmo *após a reinstalação do XAMPP*

Comment: Pode também ser pelo nome do ficheiro PHP, que não pode ter caracteres especiais(acentos, vírgulas, etc).

Comment: Obrigado @FilipeFernandes mas, como pode ver no exemplo, não são usados caracteres especiais. O motivo, como mostra a resposta aceita abaixo, é outro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como estava funcionando antes da atualização, deve ser algo a ver com isso.

**Esse tipo de erro costuma ocorrer quando o Apache ou o PHP não tem acesso à pasta/arquivos do projeto.**

Pode ser que na atualização as permissões do drive D ou da pasta do projeto (ou de alguma pasta de onde ela herda) tenha sido mudadas.

Para verificar isso, clique com o botão direito do mouse na pasta do projeto, propriedade, aba segurança e clique em Avançadas. Lá será possível ver permissões e propriedade da pasta.

Outra possibilidade seria o **OneDrive**. No Windows 1709 ele passa ater um comportamento aprimorado (devido ao envio sob demanda) e precisa de permissões maiores na pasta onde ele atua.

Se vc tiver o OneDrive ativo, e a pasta do seu projeto estiver nele, vc não conseguirá usar o built-in nela e nem o Apache (pelo menos até a Microsoft resolver isso, se é que vão).

Se for este o caso, recomendo que vc coloque seu projeto **fora do Onedrive** e mande pra lá apenas as versões finais de cada atualização. Assim vc mantém seus arquivos vinculados sem perder a propriedade da pasta. (Até pq, se vc usar algum versionador, como o Git, não é muito recomendado ter OneDrive, Google Drive, ou qq/ outro armazenador em nuvem ativo na mesma pasta, pq o versionador atualiza vários arquivos a cada commit, e o aplicativo que armazena em nuvem pode se perder.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Era o OneDrive mesmo... muito obrigado!

Comment: Após fazer ```brew upgrade``` começou a dar este problema num projeto de PHP. Soluções? Não tenho nada no One Drive e tou num macOS @Kamile Pimenta